# Data from database real-time. Use websockets or not?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, websocket

*I know there are more questions like this around here (regarding websockets and Ajax requests) but I'm currently looking for the best solution in my specific case.*

I'm currenly developing a game in Javascript. It's a Single Page Application so every change should be pulled from the server without page refresh. I'm currently wondering how I should handle the 'resources in stock' (like wood, food and gold).

#### Scenario

Resources are produced every second. So for example, every minute 100 resources are produced. This should be updated live. I know, in this case it's not necessary to really update them live. I mean, I can simply calculate how much resources are produced in the current time minus the last updated time.

So no problem here, but there are a lot of different factors regarding the production of resources:

- If a player is attacked, the enemy could have robbed some of his resources. So after an attack, the resources should be updated too.
- If a player is attacked, and one of his 'productionbuildings' are damaged, he, for example, doesn't produce 1000 resources a hour, but 800 resources instead. So after a building has been demolished, the application should know the new building level to calculate the right amount of new resources.

#### Possibilities

So, how should I update the resources for the user? These are the options I think could possibly work:
* Ping a script on the server, which calculates and updates the resources, every 5 seconds.
* Set up a websocket stream and trigger it after each activity (after an attack, demolished building, ...)

Are there any other options? What would be the best way? It's not really a problem if there is a delay of 5 seconds.